# Steam version of Fallout / Fallout 2 in a window

Tags: steam, fallout-2, fallout

I've been looking to run Fallout / Fallout 2 in windowed mode; I have the steam version. Has anyone had any experience getting this to work? I'm running Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: The tag has Fallout 2, I'm presuming that you meant fallout 2?

Comment: @McKay, I understand `fallout-series` as referring to all fallout games (1-3) -- I think he's specifically asking about `Fallout` and `Fallout 2`

Comment: Hmm, I was partially basing my guess on the fact that the original fallout had not been released on Steam, but it looks like it has.

Comment: @McKay When unsure, verify!

Comment: OK, I have to ask: *windowed mode!?* why not full-screen?

Comment: @MGOwen I like to keep IM open when I'm playing Fallout in case someone needs something done in meatspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do it with stock Fallout 2, but there are mods available to do it.

For example, this one: [Timeslip Fallout 2 engine tweaks for Windows 2000/XP/Vista](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/dload.php?action=file&file_id=1067)

Comment: The link there is dead, but I found the ddraw.ini files in the respective Fallout directories. Either Steam ships with it (disabled) or I've secretly patched my own software. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You should get Killap's mod: http://www.killap.net/

It takes care of this. If you read the readme it tells you how can you do this.